# Convert node data to lat/ long > DBF to CSV conversion

Tags: qgis, convert, latitude-longitude, dbf, network-analysis

I have a DBF table with nodal data locating cycle injuries in Portland, OR. I'd like to convert the table to a .CSV. Transferring the attribute data isn't a problem, but I'd like to get lat/long values for the nodal values (circled in enclosed image).

What exactly does the node data describe, the roads as a network, and these points nodes in the network?

Is there a way to do this in bulk? If the answer involves using QGIS or ArcGIS, I'd prefer to use QGIS.

[image: DBF table]

Comment: You need to ask the provider of the data what that field means.

Comment: Well, I know they're location data, and when the dbf is opened up as part of a .shp file in Arc, it automatically "knows" where each point is supposed to be. Which leads me to believe there's something coded into the node data that arc can "read" and locate. In any case, I can't get a hold of the provider of the data, but neither can ArcMap...

Comment: the commas inside cells B1, C1 and D1 look suspect to me. I'm wondering if  some of these columns should actually be split into multiple columns. Have you tried using a different delimiter/quote setting?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't .shp, .shx files associated with the .dbf file? Then you've got a shapefile and ArcMap can automatically display the data. If so, look for the Add XY coordinates tool.

Comment: @Steven Kay the column names include meta info like the respective data type (with 'C' for character I guess and 254 as bytelength?)

Comment: @Edward Curran you should be able to dragndrop the dbf in QGIS layer window, even as standalone dbf (or use 'add vector layer...'). you can then extract the geometry with the field calculator (create lat & lng columns and fill with x & y values - see the field calculator manual for infos on how to use)